# emberjs - dynamic computed property does not trigger classNameBindings

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a mixin to validate components with texFields it looks like this, I am using `Ember.defineProperty` to create a cp on the fly with a dynamic dependant key:

```
App.ValidationMixin = Ember.Mixin.create
  classNameBindings: ['isInvalid']

  input: (e) ->
    @_super.apply this, arguments

  setup: Ember.on 'didInsertElement', ->
    unless validations = @get('validations')

    el = @autocompleteElement()

    # I had to add this to access the prop rather than it getting
    # triggered when the dynamic property changes
    if @get('isInvalid')
      el.addClass 'is-invalid'
    else
      el.removeClass 'is-invalid'

  validationMixin: Ember.on 'didInsertElement', ->
    unless validations = @get('validations')
      return

    dynamicProperty = # logic to determine dynamic property

    Ember.defineProperty this, 'isInvalid', Ember.computed dynamicProperty, 'validator.isSubmitted', ->
      # validation logic
```

The problem is, I have to manually check for `this.get('isInvalid')` rather then the property function being executed when one of the dependant keys changes.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember probably thinks that the property 'isInvalid' is not used anywhere and therefore doesn't update it. I guess that 'didInsertElement' is called after the classNameBindings property... Try to output the 'isInvalid' property in the template to check if that's the case because therefore it must be updated.

Comment: moving defineProperty to Ember.on('init' makes it all work perfectly